# Cannot add values field properly in a Pivot Table using a Data Model

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot, datamodel

I am trying to add a Pivot Table field values to a Pivot Table backed by multiple tables in a Data Model and I am quite struggling on the way to do that.
I am using the following code to add rows but can't manage to add values properly:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim cf As CubeField

Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set cf = pt.CubeFields("[Asset1].[Geography]")
cf.Orientation = xlRowField
```

If I use the following code it add values but as a count and with only 1 when there are multiple values and so the count should be different from 1, the goal would be to retrieve the sum of the values of the assets for a certain geography:

```
Set pt = Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
ptFieldDescription = "Value"

pt.AddDataField pt.CubeFields("[FundAsset1].[Value]"), ptFieldDescription
```

Many thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the solution using the developer mode, and doing it mannually while recording a macro, quite easy to do on your own if you need!